# Can a C/C++ program call a mapreduce program

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, mapreduce

I am fairly new to the hadoop domain as well as C/C++ programming. I am primarily from the Java domain. There are a couple of C++ programs that implement algorithms such as greedy, nearest neighbor, etc. I am working on parallelizing the algorithm part using hadoop although I do not want to convert the entire C++ program to mapreduce. Is is possible to call the mapreduce program (that will implement certain algorithm) from a C++ program environment?
Thanks,
Aarthi

Comment: JNI: Java <--> C.  
JNA: Java --> C

Comment: Yes you will find a mapreduce in the Qt framework you should search for QtConcurrent.

http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2007/04/26/mapreduce-in-qt-concurrent/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite possible.

You need to write two classes; `MapTask` implements a mapping function to process `key`/`value` pairs generate a set of intermediate `key`/`value` pairs and `ReduceTask` that implements a reduce function to merges all intermediate values associated with the same intermediate key.

```
class map_task
{
  public:
    typedef std::string   key_type;
    typedef std::ifstream value_type;
    typedef std::string   intermediate_key_type;
    typedef unsigned      intermediate_value_type;

    map_task(job::map_task_runner &runner);
    void operator()(key_type const &key, value_type const &value);
};

class reduce_task
{
  public:
    typedef std::string  key_type;
    typedef size_t       value_type;

    reduce_task(job::reduce_task_runner &runner);

    template<typename It>
    void operator()(typename map_task::intermediate_key_type const &key, It it, It ite)
};
```